# Modifying Metadata from PHAsset with mediaType Video fails

Tags: ios, swift, avassetexportsession, avasset, photokit

I try adding/modifying the Metadata from an `PHAsset` with `mediaType == .video` I found some Questions refering to a similar problem:

[How to change video metadata using AVAssetWriter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11648776/5227674)

[Add custom metadata to video using AVFoundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480991/add-custom-metadata-to-video-using-avfoundation)

Regarding to the Answers in these Questions I build the following snippet which is a extension of a PHAsset:

```
let options = PHVideoRequestOptions()
options.version = .original

PHImageManager.default().requestAVAsset(forVideo: self, options: options, resultHandler: {
    asset, audioMix, info in

    if asset != nil && asset!.isKind(of: AVURLAsset.self) {
        let urlAsset = asset as! AVURLAsset

        let start = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.0, 1)
        let duration = asset!.duration                    


        var exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset!, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough)
        exportSession!.outputURL = urlAsset.url
        exportSession!.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4V
        exportSession!.timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: start, duration: duration)

        var modifiedMetadata = asset!.metadata

        let metadataItem = AVMutableMetadataItem()
        metadataItem.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpaceQuickTimeUserData
        metadataItem.key = AVMetadataQuickTimeMetadataKeyRatingUser as NSString
        metadataItem.value = NSNumber(floatLiteral: Double(rating))

        modifiedMetadata.append(metadataItem)

        exportSession!.metadata = modifiedMetadata

        LogInfo("\(modifiedMetadata)")


        exportSession!.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
            let status = exportSession?.status
            let success = status == AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed
            if success {
                completion(true)
            } else {
                LogError("\(exportSession!.error!)")
                completion(false)
            }
        })
    }
})
```

When I execute this snippet, the `exportSession` failed an has the following error:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain 
Code=-3000 "Cannot create file" 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot create file, 
NSUnderlyingError=0x1702439f0 
{Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12124 "(null)"}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my mistake. To modify the metadata of an `PHAsset` with the `MediaType` `MediaType.video` you can use the following snippet, where `self` is the `PHAsset`:

First you need to create an `PHContentEditingOutput` you can do that with requesting an `PHContentEditingInput` from the `PHAsset` you want to modify. When changing an `PHAsset` you also have to set the `.adjustmentData` Value of the `PHContentEditingOutput` or else the `.performChanges()` Block will fail.

```
   self.requestContentEditingInput(with: options, completionHandler: {
        (contentEditingInput, _) -> Void in

        if contentEditingInput != nil {

            let adjustmentData = PHAdjustmentData(formatIdentifier: starRatingIdentifier, formatVersion: formatVersion, data: NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: rating))

            let contentEditingOutput = PHContentEditingOutput(contentEditingInput: contentEditingInput!)
            contentEditingOutput.adjustmentData = adjustmentData
            self.applyRatingToVideo(rating, contentEditingInput, contentEditingOutput, completion: {
                output in
                if output != nil {
                    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanged({
                        let request = PHAssetChangeRequest(for: self)
                        request.contentEditingOutput = output
                    }, completionHandler: {
                        success, error in
                        if !success {
                            print("can't edit asset: \(String(describing: error))")
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    })
```

With the snippet above, you change the `PHAsset` after modifying the `PHContentEditingOutput` in the following snippet you will see, how to set the Metadata for an User Rating:

```
private func applyRatingToVideo(_ rating: Int, input: PHContentEditingInput, output: PHContentEditingOutput, completion: @escaping (PHContentEditingOutput?) -> Void) {
    guard let avAsset = input.audiovisualAsset else { return }

    guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: avAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough) else { return }

    var mutableMetadata = exportSession.asset.metadata
    let metadataCopy = mutableMetadata

    for item in metadataCopy {
        if item.identifier == AVMetadataIdentifierQuickTimeMetadataRatingUser {
            mutableMetadata.remove(object: item)
        }
    }

    let metadataItem = AVMutableMetadataItem()
    metadataItem.identifier = AVMetadataIdentifierQuickTimeMetadataRatingUser
    metadataItem.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpaceQuickTimeMetadata
    metadataItem.key = AVMetadataQuickTimeMetadataKeyRatingUser as NSString
    metadataItem.value = NSNumber(floatLiteral: Double(rating))

    exportSession.outputURL = output.renderedContentURL
    mutableMetadata.append(metadataItem)
    exportSession.metadata = mutableMetadata
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
    exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
    exportSession.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
        if exportSession.status == .completed {
            completion(output)
        } else if exportSession.error != nil {
            completion(nil)
        }
    })
}
```

Consider, that if you do not remove the `AVMetadataItem` with the same Identifier as the one you want to add, the `AVAssetExportSession` will set multiple Items with the same Identifier for the `AVAsset`.

**NOTE:**

When you now access the Video through the `PHImageManager`-method `.requestAVAsset(forVideo:,options:,resultHandler:)` you have to pass an `PHVideoRequestOptions`-object with the `.version` variable set to `.current`. It is set as default value of the variable but if you change it to `.original` you will get the unmodified Video from that method.

Comment: Thanks for sharing a good solution! But I don't understand this part, `PHAdjustmentData(formatIdentifier: starRatingIdentifier, formatVersion: formatVersion, data: NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: rating))`, especially `NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: rating)`. Why did you use `rating` value?

Comment: It is mandatory by the `PHContentEditingoutput`. In general the plan behind it is, that any app that makes another iteration in editing your video or photo data can read out these information and deal with them. That could be especially useful when you add another filter. In this case I only add it to describe the change that has been made to the Asset. The `NSKeyedArchiver` is not mandatory, It was just a simple way to convert the rating object into `data` but you can use other ways to archieve that especially if you want to add a codable object.